# Showing a function is onto

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Define $f:[0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ by $f(x)=x^2\sin x$. Show that $f$ is onto.

My attempt:
For $n\in \mathbb N$ ,
$f((4n+1)\frac{\pi}{2})=(4n+1)^2$

And. $f((4n+3)\frac{\pi}{2})=-(4n+3)^2$.

Now for any $y\in\mathbb R$ we can find $n\in\mathbb N$ such that $y\in(-(4n+3)^2,(4n+1)^2)$. Then by intermediate value theorem there is some $x$ such that $f(x)=y$. Hence $f$ is onto. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is right but the evaluation is not right. Also highlight that $f$ is continuous.

\begin{align}
f((4n+1)\tfrac{\pi}2) &= \left((4n+1) \frac{\pi}2 \right)^2 \sin \left( (4n+1) \frac{\pi}2\right)\\
&=\left((4n+1) \frac{\pi}2 \right)^2
\end{align}